# Mirror flip CGPath

Tags: ios, core-graphics, cgcontext, cgpath, uibezierpath

I have a simple circle CGPath. 
I am having trouble flipping it horizontally, like a mirror effect.

If you are answering this question, please try to provide a full code and not only a general reference...

thx

Comment: You have not illustrated any attempt on your part. Basically your question reads like "This is what I want to do, please send the code" We have no idea where you are stuck, so it's really difficult to help you. If you can edit this for clarity, please flag it for moderator attention to be reviewed.

Answer (score 4):

```
UIBezierPath* aPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:CGRectMake( 0, -240, 240, 240 )];

// This will mirror the path

CGAffineTransform rotation = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, -1.0);

CGMutablePathRef f = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathAddPath(f, &rotation, aPath.CGPath);

CAKeyframeAnimation *pathAnimation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
pathAnimation.calculationMode = kCAAnimationPaced;
pathAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeRemoved;
pathAnimation.rotationMode = kCAAnimationRotateAutoReverse;
pathAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
pathAnimation.path = f;
pathAnimation.repeatCount = HUGE_VALF;;
pathAnimation.duration  = 5.0f;
[r2.layer addAnimation:pathAnimation forKey:nil];
```